# Remove strings in Solr that occures more then X times in other documents

Tags: solr, nutch

I have *nutch* indexing a webpage and storing the results in *solr*. 
I would like to remove sentences from all the resulting documents "content" field  where  these sentences occurs  more than X times in other documents/pages.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: Before pushing the data to solr you may have to add a logic which will check the count of the repeated thing...But I would like to know the use case behind it...it would help to guide you better

Comment: I was hoping this could be done inside solr. Basicly I want to have  a list of fairly unique sentences  for each document/page  inside solr so that the documents could  be searched for their unique and relevant data - and not searched for non-unique sentences  that are repeated on each page.